# CSS alignment problems when using jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a minor concern:

I'm currently coding a sign up form and I decided to test jQuery validate. Unfortunately the error message returned was all over the place. Not sure if its a CSS problem but I've been battling with alignment for several hours and really would appreciate some help.

[image]

As seen in the picture above **I'm trying to get the "This field is required." text directly aligned under the text field.**

This is the code I'm using so far:

**jQuery**

```
// sign up validation
$(".signup").validate();
```

**CSS**

```
.myform {
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#stylized h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#stylized p {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #b7ddf2;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#stylized label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
}

#stylized label.error {
    float: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

#stylized .small {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
}
#stylized input {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}
#stylized select {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}
#stylized button {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 169px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #42230b;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff6b9;
    border: 1px solid #db9c2e;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f7ce50;
    background: -webkitkit-gradient(linear, bottom, top, from(#f1ac33), to(#fef673));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #f1ac33, #fef673);
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#stylized button:hover {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 169px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #edb954;
    background: -webkitkit-gradient(linear, bottom, top, from(#dc9f35), to(#fed273));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #dc9f35, #fed273);
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform" >
    <form class="signup" method="post" action="#">
    <label>Username
    <span class="small">Enter a username.</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required"/>
    <label>Email
    <span class="small">Enter a valid address.</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required"/>
    <label>Password
    <span class="small">Enter a secure password.</span>
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
    <label>Confirm Password
    <span class="small">Enter your password again.</span>
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
    <label>Age
    <span class="small">Select your age range.</span>
    </label>
    <select id="age" name="age" class="required">
    <option></option>
    <option>0 - 17</option>
    <option>18 - 25</option>
    <option>26 - 40</option>
    <option>40+</option>
    </select>                
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I am using this plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: could you add a link to the jQuery plugin you're using?

Comment: It would also be helpful to state where you want your error messages.

Comment: @NicolásTorres I'm not sure I can use jsfiddle because I am using an external plugin called at http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I want them directly aligned underneath the text field (with at least 5px padding)

Comment: you *can* use jsfiddle with external plugins

Comment: @ZachL This is what I've managed to do so far: http://jsfiddle.net/d3eE9/ it keeps returning an error message each time I press submit

Comment: Well, it looks like the validate script is inserted correctly to me.  However, looks like you're loading the default js library (mootools) instead of jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your stylesheet with...

```
#stylized label.error {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 170px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You needed some update on both CSS and HTML.

Here is the CSS update given, the HTML I gave completely.

The update on HTML is,
I've placed the `<input/>` and `<select>` under a `<div>` element which has class '*fields*' for common styling and better alignment.

**CSS UPDATE**

```
#stylized label.error {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.field{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform" >
    <form class="signup" method="post" action="#">
    <label>Username
    <span class="small">Enter a username.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required"/>
    </div>
    <label>Email
    <span class="small">Enter a valid address.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required"/>
    </div>
    <label>Password
    <span class="small">Enter a secure password.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
    </div>
    <label>Confirm Password
    <span class="small">Enter your password again.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
    </div>
    <label>Age
    <span class="small">Select your age range.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="field">
        <select id="age" name="age" class="required">
            <option></option>
            <option>0 - 17</option>
            <option>18 - 25</option>
            <option>26 - 40</option>
            <option>40+</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't appear to be any of the above, html, css, or validate. In a sense its in the layout itself.

Validate is adding it directly under the input field like its expected to, but since there is no division between the input and the label then new line that forms starts under the label. If you alter your layout a bit so its divided into partitions one side labels one side inputs, and do it sort of like an old school table layout then your validate should work the way you hope.

You could use CSS to add padding or a margin to the validation error container as well, and try to push it that way, though that may not have the full desired effect either, and pending on your method of doing it may not work in all browsers accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem just weeks ago. jQuery Validate plugin inserts error message right after input. Your input has 20px bottom margin -> message is 20px below.

Solution: set input margins to 0, put each input field in div, set div margins to values input margins had.

edit: added requested example

current css:

```
#stylized input {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}
```

modified css:

```
#stylized input {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #aacfe4;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.inputContainer {
    margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}
```

current html

```
<label>Username
<span class="small">Enter a username.</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required"/>
<label>Email
<span class="small">Enter a valid address.</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required"/>
```

modified html

```
<label>Username
<span class="small">Enter a username.</span>
</label>
<div class="inputContainer">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required"/>
</div>
<label>Email
<span class="small">Enter a valid address.</span>
</label>
<div class="inputContainer">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required"/>
</div>
```

Comment: modified answer to include example

Comment: btw input is displayed inline and div is block - adding an extra float might be needed - you'll see.